# Code gets stuck at acquiring wake lock while registering with GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-wake-lock

I am using GCM for push notifications for my project, but am stuck at acquiring wake lock.

Log message:

```
09-03 17:04:05.003: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(5772): onReceive:com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
09-03 17:04:05.003: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(5772): GCM IntentService class: example.pro.GCMIntentService
09-03 17:04:05.049: V/GCMBaseIntentService(5772): Acquiring wakelock
```

Below is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.pro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="example.pro.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="example.pro.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.FriendPickerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.GcmMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".GcmMainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.NewGame"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.NewGame" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.Vs_Facebook"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.Vs_Facebook" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.RandomPlayer"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.RandomPlayer" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.Register" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.RegisterActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.SendRequest"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.SendRequest" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.PickFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.PickFriendsActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.getFinishedGames"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.getFinishedGames" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.pro.HomeScreen" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="example.pro" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

GCMIntentService----> This class file is inside `com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe` package, but my R.java file is generated inside `example.pro`. I don't know why.

```
package com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe;

import javax.management.Notification;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", GcmMainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, GcmMainActivity.name,
            GcmMainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context,
            getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error, errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        // notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +
        // context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");
        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

I also tried `<service android:name="example.pro.GCMIntentService" />` But then it is giving me an error while registering, saying that it can't instantiate service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` broadcast receiver from the Google GCM client library. This class expects the intent service to be in the main package of your app (`example.pro`) but your intent service is in a different package - `com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe`. That's why the receiver can't find the service.

You should either move the `GCMIntentService` to the main package of your app, or override `GCMBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: thank's but i have only one package in my project that is  com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe    as i already mentioned but don't know why my R.java file is generated inside example.pro . OR please help me how to override GCMBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @user2739526 If you wish the package of your app to be `com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe`, you should replace all places in your manifest that say `example.pro` with `com.thinkappz.advancedtictactoe`.

Comment: thanks it solve my problem. I were spending 2 days on this :)