# onRegistered() from GCMIntentService not called

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

onRegisterd() method from GCMIntentService not called.

In log it displays like:
onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
GCM IntentService class: com.example.dailysales.GCMIntentService
Acquiring wakelock
My AndroidManifest.XML File code is below:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.dailysales" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.example.dailysales.backgroundservice.InboxMessageLoadingService" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".GCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18598887/4195406

*You are using the `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver` broadcast receiver from the Google GCM client library. This class expects the intent service to be in the main package of your app.*

*You should either move the `GCMIntentService` to the main package of your app, or override `GCMBroadcastReceiver`.*